# AngularJS updating model's content from another model

Tags: angularjs

I've got two lists of models (posts and glossary items) that are each loaded via AJAX and displayed in their own views.  Both have a title and some HTML content.

What I'd like to do in the post view is wrap every mention of one of the glossary item titles in a link to that item.  So if I have "Orange" and "Apple" glossary items every mention of "orange" or "apple" in any of the post content will get turned into a link.

I'm not sure how to go about it since both lists are being loaded via AJAX and it doesn't know which will be there first. I'm new to Angular though so I was hoping someone could give me an idea of what direction to go in or what feature I should be looking at.

Comment: Show some html and code structure for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the highlighter [here](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/search-highlight/) , check the source code and modify it so that it can add a blue color and anchor tag, with href = your link for that item.

Also make sure you apply highlighter only after loading both the ajax reqs.